# Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

Всем добрый день.

Пытаюсь изменить св-ва загружаемого извне фрейма, но почему-то могу получить только HTMLCollection, а при обращении к ее элементам получаю undefined. Фрейм загружается из скрипта со стороннего ресурса. Получить фрейм по id не представляется возможным по причине того, что id динамический.

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.scriptService.loadExternalResources('comments').subscribe(() => {
  })

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      let attr = 'display: none;'
      let coll = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
      console.log(coll)
      console.log(coll[1])
      console.log(coll.length)
      let elem = coll[1].contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('_42ef _8u')
  }) 
}
```

В консоли отображается следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема не в отсутствии элемента указанного класса в элементе коллекции, а отсутствии всего содержимого коллекции при обращении к ней, хотя из консоли видно, что коллекция не пуста.

Comment: есть несколько нюансов, во-первых зачем вы вешаете обработчик события `load` в `ngAfterViewInit`? во-вторых почему вы работаете с `iframe` не внутри `subscribe`?

Comment: Просто при проделывании такой же операции с другим фреймом, без load тоже выдавало undefined при обращении к элементам коллекции, с ним же все заработало. А вот с этим фреймом не работает. По поводу subscribe, внутри него тоже не работает.

Comment: вставил код для предыдущего фрейма в subscribe, работает без load, вне метода без обработчика событий не работает.